# Same package name in both Java and Python

Tags: java, python, jython

In Jython, we can easily import a Java package like this:

```
Java:

package javapkg;

public class TestClassInJava {

}

Python:

from javapkg import TestClassInJava
```

However, if we have another package with the same name in Python:

```
javapkg/__init__.py:

class AnotherClassInPython:
    pass
```

And in another Python file:

```
from javapkg import AnotherClassInPython    # success
from javapkg import TestClassInJava    # ImportError: No module named TestClassInJava
```

The Python package can be successfully imported, while the Java class in the same package will unable to be imported.
Is there anyway to merge these two namespace to make them both available?

Comment: you could put all your java package in a `java` package so that its `java.mypackage`